# A word to express the idea of "human traits"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a single word that can succinctly express the idea of "human traits" or "human behaviours" or "human habits"?

Words that I have thought like race, species are not good because the sound too general and have too little link to the idea of "human traits"

Comment: I cannot understand clearly what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably ***[Culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture)*** is the word you want. Only humans have culture, so you can leave off the *human* part. There's material culture, artistic culture, economic culture, biological culture, you name it.

See also [Anthropology, Cultural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_anthropology); [Anthropology, Physical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_anthropology); and [Linguistics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler).

Comment: Would culture still sound a little broad if I only wanted to narrow down to just human habits and behaviour? I am worry that readers may find it difficult to relate to the idea of human's behaviour

Comment: Habits are habits of behavior, right? The two are not disjoint concepts. That's why I went broad; there doesn't seem to be a single concept here.